# AppCompact.v7 on Android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

When using the card view from the AppCompat library

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

on previous version of android (4.x) it works as expected given an elevation value.

However, when I run this layout code on an android 5.0 device the cards still act as views but the elevation is no longer visible and they seem to ignore padding specified in such a way:

```
card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation_small"
card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/card_padding_small"
```

Is there an easy fix/resolution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the entire XML for the `CardView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, I had the same problem. CardViews appeared differently in Kitkat and Lollipop.

The workaround I used was to add padding to the parent of cardview. if you dont have any, make it and apply padding to its parent.

Comment: Essentially, yes. The shadows don't show up on Lollipop like they do on KitKat (Tested on 2 Nexus5's, one running 4.4 the other on 5.0). Do you know if adding this padding to the parent changes the appearance on 4.4 as well or will it simply make them look the same?

Comment: it will look the same....just add padding of about 10 dp... i have done the same thing. I got what I wanted without any major layout difference in kitkat and lolipop.